# Obtain raster area using gdalinfo

Tags: raster, gdal, gdalinfo

I'm trying to get the area of a raster (without NULL cells) using gdalinfo, I read the [gdal documentation](https://gdal.org/programs/gdalinfo.html#gdalinfo) but found no parameter that would give me the area; I can calculate it from the histogram obtained, by subtracting the values in the first histogram bin (which where the NULL in this case) from the width*height values (size) and multiplying by the resolution, but hist function takes some time and maybe NULL cell will have another value in other raster files. This is the function.

`gdalinfo -json  -hist raster.tif | jq ((.size[0]*.size[1]-.bands[0].histogram.buckets[0])*.geoTransform[1]*.geoTransform[1])/10000'`

Answer (score 2):

It don't think you'll get this out of `gdalinfo`, although it would be possible if you included null cells in your calculation.

Instead, I would reclassify all non-null cells to have a value of 1, and all null cells to have a value of 0, then do a sum across the entire raster, and then multiply that value by the area of one pixel.